# How to populate fields based on references/models?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I have two user schemas:

```js
UserSchema1 = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstName:{
        type: String
    }
})

UserSchema2 = new mongoose.Schema({
    email:{
        type: String
    }
})


ChatMessageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        senderId:{
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            refPath: 'onModel',
            required: true
        },
        onModel:{
            type: String,
            required: true,
            enum: ['userSchema1', 'userSchema2']
        },
        message: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
})
```

Now, I need to populate all the chat messages. I need results as following:

```
[
    {
        senderId:{
            firstName or email
        },
        onModel: userSchema1 / userSchema2,
        message: "message"
    },
    {

    }, ...
]
```

That is if the sender is UserSchema1, then it should populate firstName and if it is UserSchema2, it should populate email. I cannot populate all the fields, because there are more than 20 fields in each collection.

In short, If UserSchema1, it should just populate firstName, and if UserSchema2, it should just populate email.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can use this schema for a chat it's better than your schema
use user Id and with Id get user data

```
   MessageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      from: {
        type: string,
        required: true,
      },
      to: {
        type: string,
        required: true,
      },
      time: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now(),
      },
      message: {
        type: string,
        required: true,
      },
    });


ChatSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        firstUserId:{
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            required: true,
        },
        secondUserId:{
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            required: true,
        },
        Chat: MessageSchema,
})
```

and data will be as this way

```
[
  {
    firstUserId: "hjakdsf323275lks",
    secondUserId: "asdfe2342232aas",
    Chat: [
      {
        from: "hjakdsf323275lks",
        to: "asdfe2342232aas",
        time: "18/7/2020 20:06:09",
        message: "Hi ",
      },
      {
        from: "asdfe2342232aas",
        to: "hjakdsf323275lks",
        time: "18/7/2020 21:07:09",
        message: "hello ",
      },....
    ],
  },
];
```

Comment: The schema which I have mentioned is just a part of the actual schema. The application is already developed and I need to fix this issue. Is there any way, I can fix this issue without changing the schema? PS: Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: No problem, just if you can give me full schema to fix it

Comment: I guess sharing the full schema will make things even more confusing. The schema which I have shared covers all the required details. Let me know what exactly you need?

Comment: because I didn't understand your schema, I want now how the flow in the all schema

Comment: if you want to contact me this my Github account
https://github.com/ha77an